# I am not able to see the same output of the react native application as on web and android emul irrelevant of the code being compiled without error

Tags: react-native, web, expo, android-emulator, rendering

[Web view of app[endering on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWylj.png)]

[android emulator view of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSSuS.png)

As you can see it is not rendering all the component on the emulator or device but on web.

Not able to understand the problem either it is related to rendering or native component issue .

Comment: Please post code. Probably it‘s a different flexbox default between app and web behavior

Comment: Please do not use code images copy/past it in the post with a good formatting for a better lisibility